# How to check property of JavaToolbar button with UFT/QTP?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, vbscript

There is a toolbar in the java application with buttons: ..., security, tools, login, logout.

[image: java toolbar]

UFT object spy can reach down to a certain button, but in script (descriptive programming) UFT can only see `JavaToolbar`.

```
nowYouSeeMe = JavaWindow("label:=WinTitle").JavaToolbar("attached text:=ToolbarName").Exist(0)    'True
nowYouDoN_t = JavaWindow("label:=WinTitle").JavaToolbar("attached text:=ToolbarName").JavaButton("label:=logout").Exist(0)    'False
```

So I can not get property, e.g. `enabled`, of a certain button. Just can press it like:

```
JavaWindow("label:=WinTitle").JavaToolbar("attached text:=ToolbarName").Press "logout"
```

Is there any possibility to get property of a button? (Guess it should be the same like in JavaMenu, get property of menu item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetItemProperty([item], [property])` method is used to check property of `JavaToolbar` item. E.g.:

```
enabledProp = JavaWindow("label:=WinTitle").JavaToolbar("attached text:=ToolbarName").GetItemProperty("logout", "enabled")
```